# Does it matter if I have a made a website responsive or not. If I show the website on a projector?

Tags: responsive-design, css-position, responsive, margins

So I have to give a presentation of a website I made. So I didn't have time to make it responsive. I have used `position:relative` and `px`units in margins and all. Will it change layout of website if I use duplicate option in windows 10 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the projector has a resolution similar to a regular computer screen, it won't make a difference.

Comment: Problem is I can't know that before the day of presentation

Comment: But usually projectors *do*  have resolutions similar to computer monitors (i.e. definitely not similar to mobile devices...).

Comment: And if your code doesn't contain the usual "viewport tag" to make it responsive, the website will most likely be zoomed to the size of the projector, so you can imagine what your website will look like then.